# Link of anchor tag is also printing in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, printing, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I have a table of employee's salary list. I wrap the employee id with an `anchor` tag to show salary history of each individual employees. The problem is when I print the table the `link` for individual salary history is also printed under the employee id.

**Here is a screen shot print preview:**

[image]

**Blade**

```
<div class="d-section col-md-12">
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
            <th>Worked</th>
            <th>Basic</th>
            <th>OT Rate</th>
            <th>OT Hour</th>
            <th>OT Amount</th>
            <th>Basic Amount</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Signature</th>
            <th>Finger</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($employees as $employee)
            <tr>
                <td><a href="{{ action('SalaryController@show',[$employee->id]) }}">{{ $employee->eid }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ $employee->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $employee->designation }}</td>
                <td>{{ $employee->start }}</td>
                <td>{{ $employee->end }}</td>
                <td>{{ $employee->worked }}</td>
                <td>{{ $employee->basic }}</td>
                <td>{{ $employee->ot_rate }}</td>
                <td>{{ $employee->ot_hour }}</td>
                <td>{{ $employee->ot_amount }}</td>
                <td>{{ $employee->basic_amount }}</td>
                <td>{{ $employee->ot_amount + $employee->basic_amount }}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    {!! Form::open(['action'=>['SalaryController@destroy',$employee->id],'class'=>'no-print','method'=>'delete','onsubmit'=>'return deleteConfirm()']) !!}
                    {!! Form::submit('X',['class'=>'element btnn btn-danger']) !!}
                    <br/>
                    <a href="{{ action('SalaryController@edit',[$employee->id]) }}" class="element btnn btn-warning" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
                    <br/>
                    <a href="{{ action('SalaryController@payment',[$employee->id]) }}" class="element btnn btn-success" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span></a>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just create a CSS class for your anchors and hide them using that class?

```
<a href="{{ action('SalaryController@show',[$employee->id]) }}" class="hiddenTab">foo</a>
<a href="#" class="only-print">foo</a>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.only-print{
    display:none;
}
@media print{
    a.hiddenTab {
        display:none;
    }
    .only-print{
        display:block;
    }
}
```

All the anchors you'd want to hide would just use `class="hiddenTab"`.
If you want to hide all a tags which have href set, you can do this:

```
a[href] { display: none; }
```

Comment: I have tried your both methods. But it hides the content too. I want to hide the link and keep the employee id.

Comment: You can try printing/echo after the anchor tag  echo "$employee->eid";

Comment: Yes!!! This is a good idea. I can use two anchor tag. One will visible in browser with clickable link, It will completely hide in printing and another one without link and only visible in print.

Comment: yeah give it a try ..go on @smartrahat